# Нужна информация по шедулерам для встроенных систем

Tags: c++, c, микроконтроллеры, планировщик-задач

Добрый день.

Когда-то давно я применял шедулер для микроконтроллера [http://www.ucos-ii.com](http://www.ucos-ii.com/). Довольно приятная вещь, хотя и с ограниченной функциональностью. Но с тех пор эта контора заглохла. Подскажите информацию по подобным вещам. Может быть кто-нибудь знает форум, где обсуждаются похожие вещи.

Спасибо.

UPD1:

Оказалось, что контора не заглохла, просто переехала на другой хостинг: https://www.micrium.com/. И при этом контору купил Silicon Labs.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону FreeRTOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подобных ОСРВ для микроконтроллеров довольно много, перечень можно посмотреть [здесь](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_real-time_operating_systems). Достаточно популярной является FreeRTOS (она бесплатна и по ней много материала в сети), embOS, MicroC/OS от Micrium